# Can Aerospike be used as an alternate to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage, aerospike

I am new to both the technologies, so need some guidance here

I have an S3 bucket of lots of images (20 million, 870GB) , which unfortunately has poorly thought of keys which makes the read process slow (1s - 1.8s atleast for a read).
We are planning to migrate this to a better read optimised bucket.

Then I came across aerospike and in some docs I read that we can even store images as blobs in the key value pair in aerospike. While the storage consumption would be high, the read would be faster than anything else given that it uses SSD integration.

Would it be recommended to use Aerospike to store keys like S3 and the values would then be the corresponding images? Is there any other alternative to S3 that has a faster read?

Comment: I am skeptical that your performance issue in S3 is related to the key structure, as I have buckets with millions of objects with no thought given to the key structure, and access times in the tens of milliseconds.  It seems more likely that there is a problem with your code or environment.

Comment: Could it be possible because of the bucket location in Singapore? http://blog.takipi.com/aws-olypmics-speed-testing-amazon-ec2-s3-across-regions/    I am accessing it from India

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Aerospike is not an alternative for S3. They are meant for different purposes. Aerospike is a key-value store which is used as OLTP database. S3 is file storage service. Note that Aerospike has a limit on how large a record can be. Its 1MB (max allowed value for write-block-size). If your objects are <1MB, then you may consider Aerospike for your use case.